# How to convert "/" to "\" in javascript using replace method

Tags: javascript

The path is like "C:/TEST/", and I wanna convert it to "C:\TEST\", and I searched a lot and uneasy to made it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\` denotes the start of an escape sequence, so it has to be escaped with another `\`.

To replace globally, you need to use regex, which requires even more character escaping:

```
 > 'C:/TEST/'.replace(/\//g, '\\')
 "C:\TEST\"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"C:/TEST/".replace(/\//g, '\\')
```